# Draw random number for each object in array and remove object with lowest value

Tags: java, random

As in title, i need to draw a random number againist all objects of an array and remove object with lowest drawn number. One way will be to save all drawn values and then compare them with each other. Is there is an efficent way to do this? Pesudo code :

```
while(!myArray.isEmpty) {
    for(String str : myArray) {
        // draw a random number
        // do some more stuff/save number into a map.
    }
// remove object with lowest number (or draw again if there is conflict between lowest numbers)
}
```

Comment: Why not just remove one at a random index?

Comment: Good question. I need to draw random cards from deck for users of my game and remove user with lowest card. Then another round till last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I would recommend using a `List` because you can't really "remove" elements from an array efficiently. Also you don't need to save all radom numbers and then find the lowest one, you can to that at the same time.

```
while(!myList.isEmpty()) {
  double lowestRandom = 1.0;
  int lowestIndex; //for efficient removal, save index instead of element
  for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    double random = Math.random();
    if(random < lowestRandom) {
      lowestRandom = random;
      lowestIndex = i;
    }
  }
  myList.remove(lowestIndex);  
}
```

Comment: Thankyou dear. You saved my brain from overheating. Sometimes solution is very simple but we can't figure it out. Thats why i love stackoverflow.

Comment: Note that you have to initialize `lowestRandom` with something `>=1` so that the `random < lowestRandom` condition is satisfied in the first iteration. I just edited that in :)

Comment: No problem bro. M not beginner. I just overclocked my brain along with less sleep. M having difficulty keeping my eyes open. Evr happend to you?

Comment: Definitely been there. Keep it up :)